# Calculating the empirical mean of given random variable using R

Tags: r, chi-squared-distribution

I was reading a Wikipedia page regarding the chi-square distribution: [Chi-squared distribution (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

It says the expected value of a chi square RV equals k where k is the dgf. I've tried to verify this conclusion by calculating the empirical mean in R
`x <- seq(0, 10, length = 100), sum(x * dchisq(x, df = 8))`
, it gives 44.66 as a result which is different from the dgf k, i.e., 8 in this example.
In contrast, `y <- seq(-3, 3, length = 100), sum(y * dnorm(y))` would give the correct answer, which is 0.
Can anyone point out where my fault is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probability density is not probability mass.

To find the expected value you need to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} x \,f_X(x) dx $, where $f_X(x)$ is `dchisq(x)`.

You can compute this in R using `integrate(function(x) x * dchisq(x, df = 8), lower = 0, upper = N)`, for some suitably big number `N`.

Your code gives the wrong result for two reasons:

1. If you want to approximate the integral by discretising it, you need to evaluate `sum(diff(x)[1] * x * dchisq(x, df = 8))`, i.e. take into account the width of each slice.
2. The upper bound of 10 is too low for a distribution with an expected value of 8.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It clarifies all my confusions regarding this approximation!